# how to display date and time both in xScale in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: in]

[image]
how to display date and time both in xScale in D3 ? I am struggling to show this. As image shows `06 PM` along with this I can have date info also.

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h

```
createdTime : 1568720732134
```

code-

```
var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
            return d.createdTime;
        });

var xScale = d3
            .scaleTime()
            .range([0, width])
            .domain(xDomain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the x axis's [tickFormat()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat) method to return custom tick values, and [d3.timeFormat()](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) to create formatting methods that will map your timestamps to correctly formatted strings.

For instance, if you always wanted to show the date and time for the first tick, and time for all others, you could use:

```
const formatToDateAndTime = d3.timeFormat("%a %d %-I%p"); // e.g. Tue 17 2PM
const formatToTime = d3.timeFormat("%-I%p"); // e.g. 2PM

xAxis.tickFormat((d, index) => {
  if(index === 0) {
    return formatToDateAndTime(d);
  } else {
    return formatToTime(d);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have added this in my code, I am seeing first tick is not completely visible if I add this.  https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h

Comment: It looks fine to me. Do you have an image of what you're seeing? Is it that you need to provide more margin on the left?

Comment: https://yhm8h.csb.app/ can you check in this.  what if i only wants to add condition for index 0 not the others, can you guide me. because I can have date data only also.

Comment: I'm seeing the full Sep 14 6PM at the first tick.

Comment: I don't understand the other question. The example I gave does have one format for the 0 index and another format for the rest.

Comment: let me explain this, I only want if(index === 0) {
    return formatToDateAndTime(d);
  } for my i dont want to give else formatToTime(d);.. It should take by default with respect to data for this example https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-galileo-h3ipy I dont want to show only time in xaxis

Comment: You can return any format that you want. https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format these are all of the formatting options. Just create your own formatting function as I've done in the example with d3.timeFormat() and then use that.

Comment: Thanks I will check it